# Get client certificate in stream_socket_server without verify_peer set to true for gemini server

Tags: php, ssl

I'm trying to write a [gemini](https://geminiprotocol.net/) server in PHP.
For it to work correctly in all circumstances I need to get the client certificate, if the client sends it.

If I create the context and socket like this

```
$context = stream_context_create(options: [
  'ssl' => [
    'local_cert' => "path/to/file",
    'local_pk' => "path/to/key",

    'allow_self_signed' => true,
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'capture_peer_cert' => true,
  ],
]);

$socket = stream_socket_server(
  address: "tls://localhost:1965",
  context: $context
);
```

I can accept connections like this

```
$connection = stream_socket_accept(
  socket: $socket,
  timeout: -1,
  peer_name: $peer
);
```

Connections can be established without error. But when the client is sending a certificate, I can't get it, because the `peer_certificate` in the context parameters isn't set.

```
$streamParams = stream_context_get_params($resource);
$clientCertificate = $streamParams['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'] ?? null; # always null
```

When I set `verify_peer` to `true`, then `peer_certificate` is set to an `OpenSSLCertificate` object. But then requests from the client without a certificate result in a `false` `$connection` and these errors:

```
Warning: stream_socket_accept(): Could not get peer certificate in [...]
Warning: stream_socket_accept(): Failed to enable crypto in [...]
Warning: stream_socket_accept(): Accept failed: Success in [...]
```

I checked python implementations of gemini servers, and in python there is a `verify_mode` that you can set to `CERT_OPTIONAL`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL

I couldn't find anything like this for PHP.
Is there even a way to optionally get the client certificate?

--

Answer to me currently is:
Not possible until https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80770 is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `verify_peer` is false then the server will not request a certificate from the client, the client will thus send no certificate and therefore no certificate can be captured.

There does not seem to be a way to just request the client certificate and capture it without verification. There is also an open bug about this - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80770 - unfixed since nearly 3 years.

> ... and in python there is a verify_mode that you can set to CERT_OPTIONAL

This does not solve the problem of certificate validation. It just means that it is accepted that the client does not send a certificate even if requested. But if the client sends a certificate it must still be valid.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I misunderstood what exactly `verify_peer` meant then. If the server would be fine with no certificate even when `verify_peer` is true, then it would be like the `CERT_OPTIONAL` mode in python and what would be needed for a functioning gemini server.

Comment: @dweipert: *"I misunderstood what exactly verify_peer meant then"* - no wonder because the PHP documentation is insufficient (if not wrong) in this regard. *"what would be needed for a functioning gemini server. "* - as I said, the functionality you want (just get the certificate) is not possible. Even CERT_OPTIONAL (which is not what you want) is not possible since `verify_peer` seems to be only a boolean in PHP, not a bitmap with feature flags as in OpenSSL.

Comment: Sorry then it seems I'm still a bit confused. I understand the python documentation for `CERT_OPTIONAL` as "certificate is sent => verify and capture" and "certificate is not send => don't capture". In both cases the connection is established and a response can be sent. Is that now that it means? I understand that the latter is not possible in PHP because there's no mode like that.

Comment: @dweipert: this is the correct understanding of CERT_OPTIONAL. What you want though based on my understanding of your question and what neither PHP nor python provide is "certificate is send => capture but don't verify". With OpenSSL this can be done by implementing a verify callback which accepts any certificate - but this kind of interface is not exposed in Python or PHP.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I didn't mean that the certificate shouldn't be verified. It's just that I observed that the server breaks when there's no certificate when `verify_peer` is set to true, but doesn't even ask for a certificate when `verify_peer` is set to false. So I wanted something in-between and thought that that has to mean that `verify_peer` needs to be "false but ask for a certificate" and not just `true`, since that also means denying connections without certificate.